# Set table name in SpringData Jpa Repository instead of in entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a JPA entity, which I want to store exactly with the same fields in two different tables for different purposes.

I assumed, that there is a possibility to set which table to actually store data in Spring Data Jpa repository, but couldn't find how to do it.
Is it possible?

If not, what is the best way to achieve my goal with spring data jpa and without copying the entity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to define an abstract class for your entity using [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation. You can specify your field mappings in this class. Then have two separate entity classes which inherits your abstract class and each of those two can map to their own table.